# Can I check the caller function of an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have a **webshop** in **laravel** and when I load the search, the webpage make an **ajax** call with the same **url** and I don't know who is the function what make this call. I checked the source of this call in the chrome network tab but it point to the `app.js`. Can I check the full stack trace of this call?

Comment: Maybe take a look at using the debugger in the browser :) https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Seems the chrome network tab write the full stack trace. I tried to use the console.trace() function to check the full trace but same result. The source of this call is the app.js.